# C# XML querying using XPath containing a namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

In C# I'm struggling to understand how to query XML using XPath that includes a namespace.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SomeEntity xmlns="http://www.example.com/Schemas/SomeEntity/2023/01">
  <Child>
    <TextValue>Some text</TextValue>
  </Child>
</SomeEntity>
```

XPath:

`/SomeEntity[@xmlns="http://www.example.com/Schemas/SomeEntity/2023/01"]/Child/TextValue`

C#:

`XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath); \\ doc being of type XmlDocument`

`SelectNodes` always results in an empty `XmlNodeList`.

What's the best way in C# to resolve XPath queries that include a namespace in this way?

I get the same result when using `XDocument`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string xpath = @"/SomeEntity[@xmlns=""http://www.example.com/Schemas/SomeEntity/2023/01""]/Child/TextValue";
var results = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use LINQ to XML.

There is no need to hardcode the default namespace. The `GetDefaultNamespace()` call gets it for you.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<SomeEntity xmlns='http://www.example.com/Schemas/SomeEntity/2023/01'>
          <Child>
            <TextValue>Some text</TextValue>
          </Child>
        </SomeEntity>");
    
    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    string TextValue = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "TextValue")?.FirstOrDefault().Value;
    Console.WriteLine("TextValue='{0}'", TextValue);
}
```

**Output**

```
TextValue='Some text'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially the `GetDefaultNamespace()` tip as I was thinking it was a little crazy to need to hard code this. I'm looking at a generic solution that takes any XML and any compatible XPath to query it, so this looks like good foundations to work out a solution from :) I'll have a play with the solution provided.

Comment: @Gavin, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: No problem, I will do. I'm struggling to work out how to apply a namespaced xpath query using linq though. Trying to parse the original query and break it up into individual linq statements. Still playing though.

Answer (score 0):

For querying with the `xmlns` attibute condition, with `@xmlns` is not working. Instead, you need [`namespace-uri()`](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt/0596000537/re55.html).

**Pre-requisites**:

1. Must add the XML namespace for query.
2. Provide the namespace prefix in the query.

**For `XmlDocument`**

```cs
string xpath = @"//se:SomeEntity[namespace-uri()='http://www.example.com/Schemas/SomeEntity/2023/01']/se:Child/se:TextValue";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("se", "http://www.example.com/Schemas/SomeEntity/2023/01");
        
var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath, mgr);
Console.WriteLine(nodes.Count);
Console.WriteLine(nodes.Item(0).FirstChild.Value);
```

**For `XDocument`**

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;

string xpath = @"//se:SomeEntity[namespace-uri()='http://www.example.com/Schemas/SomeEntity/2023/01']/se:Child/se:TextValue";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("se", "http://www.example.com/Schemas/SomeEntity/2023/01");
var results = xDoc.XPathSelectElements(xpath, mgr);
    
Console.WriteLine(results.FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
```